# Wireless stops working when desktop powered on (wired connection still works)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection

Background info:
Comcast cable internet and TV
Regular modem
Linksys WRT54G router
Windows7 desktop

The problem I'm seeing is that our wireless connection cuts out about 5 minutes after turning on our main desktop.  Turn off the main desktop and wireless begins to work again.  Throughout all of this, the wired connection works fine, and I have no problem connecting to the router either.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your desktop has a bluetooth adapter installed? Some bluetooth adapters are known to cause WIFI coexistance issues.

Comment: No bluetooth adapters are installed.